# How can I access the values via python in an XML that is structured as follows?

Tags: python, xml

I am having difficulties accessing the values in an XML using a python script. How can you go about accessing Value1-Value4 here? I have tried using the findall() function, but nothing returns.

```
tree =ET.parse('example.xml')

root=tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall("row"):
    print(child)
```

The XML looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<entities xmlns="http://www.example.com">
<entity id="Title" dataDate="2018-08-31">
<spreadsheetContainer name="ContainerA">
<row>
<col name="A">Value1</col>
<col name="B">Value2</col>
<col name="C">Value3</col>
<col name="D">Value4</col>
</row>
</spreadsheetContainer>
</entity>
</entities>
```

Comment: Your xml snippet is invalid. Please post a proper MCVE.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I adjusted the xml to provide a complete example, is this what you meant by MCVE?

Comment: The `row` element doesn't contain any text as such, just the individual `col` values.  You want to loop over `col` instead (perhaps with a selector to only look for `col`s inside a `row`).

Comment: What would that look like? Replacing row with col still returns nothing, looping over the child element also returns nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: the tags you're looking for is not "row" but "col".

Second point: those tags are not direct children of the root node, they are nested in entity −>  spreadsheetContainer -> row, so you need to use an XPath expression (or to manually traverse the dom, but xpath does it for you...)

Third point: your XML is namespaced (cf the `xmlns="http://www.example.com` attrib in the root tag) so you need to namespace the xpath expression (or any tag lookup actually).

So the code you want is actually:

```
from lxml.etree import ElementTree as ET

namespace = "{http://www.example.com}"
path = "{0}entity/{0}spreadsheetContainer/{0}row/{0}col".format(namespace)
root = ET.parse("example.xml")
values = [col.text for col in root.findall(path)]
```